# Where to find programming exercises for applicative functors?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, applicative

I've been reading about applicative functors, notably in the Functional Pearl by McBride and Paterson.  But I'd like to solidify my understanding by doing some exercises.  I'd prefer programming exercises but proof exercises are OK too.
**What exercises will help me learn to program effectively with applicative functors?**

Individual exercises are OK as are pointers to exercises listed elsewhere.

Comment: I can't suggest exercises, but you could look at applicative functors that aren't monads (a crucial question seems to be "why design an applicative functor when it is less powerful than a monad?"). The multi error applicative (in Paterson and McBride) is one, there are also Doaitse Swierstra's parsers, an animation one _Active_ in Andy Gill and Kevin Matledge's Chalkboard plus I think Andy Gill and colleagues' Kansas Lava is based on an applicative functor.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems amusing to post some questions as an answer. This is a fun one, on the interplay between `Applicative` and `Traversable`, based on sudoku.

(1) Consider

```
data Triple a = Tr a a a
```

Construct

```
instance Applicative Triple
instance Traversable Triple
```

so that the `Applicative` instance does "vectorization" and the `Traversable` instance works left-to-right. Don't forget to construct a suitable `Functor` instance: check that you can extract this from either of the `Applicative` or the `Traversable` instance. You may find

```
newtype I x = I {unI :: x}
```

useful for the latter.

(2) Consider

```
newtype (:.) f g x = Comp {comp :: f (g x)}
```

Show that

```
instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (f :. g)
instance (Traversable f, Traversable g) => Traversable (f :. g)
```

Now define

```
type Zone = Triple :. Triple
```

Suppose we represent a `Board` as a vertical zone of horizontal zones

```
type Board = Zone :. Zone
```

Show how to rearrange it as a horizontal zone of vertical zones, and as a square of squares, using the functionality of `traverse`.

(3) Consider

```
newtype Parse x = Parser {parse :: String -> [(x, String)]} deriving Monoid
```

or some other suitable construction (noting that the library `Monoid` behaviour for |Maybe| is inappropriate). Construct

```
instance Applicative Parse
instance Alternative Parse  -- just follow the `Monoid`
```

and implement

```
ch :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parse Char
```

which consumes and delivers a character if it is accepted by a given predicate.

(4) Implement a parser which consumes any amount of whitespace, followed by a single digit (0 represents blanks)

```
square :: Parse Int
```

Use `pure` and `traverse` to construct

```
board :: Parse (Board Int)
```

(5) Consider the constant functors

```
newtype K a x = K {unK :: a}
```

and construct

```
instance Monoid a => Applicative (K a)
```

then use `traverse` to implement

```
crush :: (Traversable f, Monoid b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> b
```

Construct `newtype` wrappers for `Bool` expressing its conjunctive and disjunctive monoid structures. Use `crush` to implement versions of `any` and `all` which work for any `Traversable` functor.

(6) Implement

```
duplicates :: (Traversable f, Eq a) => f a -> [a]
```

computing the list of values which occur more than once. (Not completely trivial.) (There's a lovely way to do this using differential calculus, but that's another story.)

(7) Implement

```
complete :: Board Int -> Bool
ok :: Board Int -> Bool
```

which check if a board is (1) full only of digits in [1..9] and (2) devoid of duplicates in any row, column or box.

Comment: I agree that these are great exercises.  They could be improved for contemporary Haskell with a few tweaks: * the use roll-your-own sum-of-product generics, which is part of the point of the exercise, but we now have GHC Generics.  It would be ideal to re-render this exercise using that, errr, idiom.  * The Triple / Zone abstraction is great for the exercise but makes it harder to model Sudoku rules where there are node interdependencies (such as noDups).

Answer (score 12):

A great way to practice is to use `Parsec` in an applicative rather than a monadic style.  Most parsers are purely applicative, so you shouldn't need to use `do` notation ever.

Eg. for expressions:

```
import qualified Text.Parsec as P
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P
import Control.Applicative

data Expr = Number Int | Plus Expr Expr

lex = P.makeTokenParser ...  -- language config

expr = number <|> plus
    where
    number = Number <$> P.integer lex
    plus = Plus <$> number <* P.symbol lex "+" <*> expr
```

Comment: I'm curious--can you give some common or at least reasonable examples that you *can't* parse with an applicative functor but can with a monad?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis, *formally* they are equivalent in power, at least over a finite alphabet, but in kind of a pathological way (they both support infinite grammars). But a good example of where you would (reasonably) need a monad would be if you had a language which could define new grammatical constructs that should be taken into account later in the parse.  `Applicative` can't change its *structure* based on its *content*, `Monad` can.

Comment: +1 When I saw the title, I also immediately thought of Parsec. It's a great way to practice solving interesting, nontrivial, yet simple problems.

Comment: Imagine parsing a language spec followed by something written in that language. You can't _easily_ to that with applicative, but with a monad it's trivial.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Applicative). It comes with a good explanation from the ground up and some exercises along the way.

Answer (score 4):

For example: [Applicative Functors](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures/2012-03-22.html)

Comment: This link seems dead, but [this is page at the Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures/*):

[Functors](https://web.archive.org/web/20130803145920/http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures/09-functors.html) ;

[Applicative functors](https://web.archive.org/web/20130803134207/http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures/10-applicative.html)